# i want test iphone app without developer certificate. i don't have jail breaker also please help me friends

Tags: ios, testing

my app is ready to test in my iPhone/ipad. so plase tell me the procedure for testing my app without developer certificate. how to take my build file.

Comment: I dont think it is possible

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer. It's `not possible`. If you want to install build on device, you must have developer certificate and your device must configure with provisioning profile.

Comment: how to take the build file

Comment: If you haven't certificate, You can't take build for device..

Comment: please send me the procedure for taking build file.

Comment: certificate is payable or free

Comment: You must have developer account with apple(must pay) then only you can create certificate and provisioning profile. see this link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ProvisioningDevelopment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH104-SW1

Comment: how can i get that certificate.

Comment: see this link https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/certificates/

Comment: why some body using test flight. for testing

Comment: I think, you are beginner in ios. Just google.

Comment: [{"prodid":"934","prodname":"BULLION Satin Gold finish Ball Pen","imageurl":"simg51f0ee2797394.jpg","description":"BULLION Satin Gold finish","price":"BULLION-NA-600.00-0.00","color":"Gold"}]

Comment: this my json response. i want to update my product details in a view so please give me the example code for that

Comment: Is this webservice response? and you want to know how do parse it?

Comment: http://www.bikrionline.com/product-detail-json-new.php?prodid=934&catid=62&scatid=154# this is the url

Comment: Do you wanna parse it?

Comment: yes i want to pasrse it

Comment: what happen sir, is it working?